# How to communicate with parent class that work is complete - Java

Tags: java, android

I've got a service in Android, but the `IntentService` will not know when to be killed - I know this isn't proper use of IntentService (that you shouldn't need to call stopSelf()).

```
public class VideoService extends IntentService {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mCamera2Video = new Camera2Video();
    mCamera2Video.start()
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //My service doesn't know when to be destroyed though!

    mCamera2Video.closeCamera();
    mCamera2Video.stopBackgroundThread();
}
```

I need to be able to call `stopSelf()` from somewhere inside of the `mCamera2Video` instance after it's completed. In this instance `mCamera2Video` both starts and finishes a video recording session, automatically stopping after 10 seconds. The `Service` then needs to know how to shut down afterwards.

```
public class Camera2Video
        implements MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {

    private void stopRecordingVideo() {
    //Notify VideoService that I am complete!!
    }

}
```

How do I do this? I'm not really familiar with Java but I'm thinking of:

- passing a callback into the `mCamera2` instance that will trigger in the `VideoService`
- I believe I should be able to implement an interface?

Thanks!

Comment: "*passing a callback into the mCamera2 instance that will trigger in the VideoService*" - I would recommend this approach.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I've been looking for docs on use of callbacks in Java (I'm more on JavaScript side). Is this using the `Callback callback` style/class?

Comment: Nope. A callback is as simple as defining an `interface` (or use an existing interface which declares a method with the signature & return type you want). You'd then accept instances of that type in `Camera2Video` either via constructor or a method: `public Camera2Video(Runnable callback)`. Store it as a field so you can call it in `stopRecordingVideo`. Now, to create the callback, you could use a lambda to implement it: `Runnable code = () -> { ... };` (the lambda declaration depends on the method in the interface). Let me know if you're still struggling.

Comment: Can you update your question with information related to `Camera2Video` ? What does it do? Starts camera and begins recording?

Comment: @Sagar Yeah, so it automatically records 10 minutes of video, and the `Camera2Video` self closes the Camera. However, after the service needs to know to shut down

Comment: @njho Does your service only triggers video capture or does some post processing too?

Comment: @Sagar It would trigger video capture. Post-processing unknown at this time